# How to resolve Visual code marketplace server error 503 issue?

Tags: visual-studio-code, marketplace

I have the following issue with Visual code I Already uninstall or install VC even I changed in different internet networks I want to search and install new extension  in marketplace visual code. but I'm receiving the following error

> Server returned 503

Do somebody knows how to fix it??

Comment: This is likely due to the ongoing Azure outage that is occurring at the time of writing.

Comment: @vcsjones Are you experimented the same behavior ?

Comment: I'm in Australia and yes I am experiencing the same issue (a picture of an unhappy robot with "Sorry! Our services aren't available right now") when I go to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/ I have voted to close this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice to meet you.

I'm sure your problem is related with VSCode downtime :)

[image: Visual Studio Code is back !!!]

More information about this: https://twitter.com/code/status/1037215136812032001

Comment: Thanks it is working again.

Answer (score 1):

Azure is currently experiencig a failure in US which broke some global services including vs marketplace - https://mobile.twitter.com/code/status/1037174137054158848